# A Nothing for Associations

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

In the same way that `Nothing` disappears from `List`s, is there a built-in that when it appears as the value in an association the whole key/value pair disappears?

In other words, is there something that makes `<|a -> 1, b -> associationNothing|>` evaluate to `<|a->1|>`?  (`Nothing` doesn't work for this purpose.)

If there is no equivalent, can we construct one?

Comment: I think you will need to apply `DeleteCases[#, Nothing] &` to the association

Comment: Don't know of anything built in. As for "can we construct one", we can surely do something, but we'd need to know some sample use cases. As it stands right now, we already have `Values[<|a -> 1, b -> Nothing|>]` giving `{1}`. And we have `<|a -> 1, Nothing|>` resolving to `<|a -> 1|>`. And we have `DeleteCases[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> Nothing|>, Nothing]` giving `<|"a" -> 1|>`. So, in what way are these unsatisfactory for the use cases you envision?

Comment: `<|a -> 1, b -> 2|> // KeyDrop[b]` ?

Comment: @lericr `Map[f, <| a->1, b->Nothing |>]` gives `<|a->f[1], b->f[Nothing]|>`, for example.

Comment: Something could be done with KeyDrop but I don't know a priori which keys will have Nothing as their value, so doing an explicit KeyDrop as @Syed suggests doesn't scale.  `DeleteCases` as @Coolwater suggests can work, but of course we can do similar tricks with List to delete Null values.  `Nothing` is nice because you don't have to think or add this additional step.

Comment: Interesting. So you'd want `Map[f, <| a->1, b->Nothing |>]` to give `<|a->f[1], b->Nothing|>`? If the Nothing was elided during construction of an Association, then this example wouldn't pertain, but maybe that's exactly why you'd want that?

Comment: Right, I don't want `b ->` at all, if its value was Nothing to begin with!

Comment: I'm actually starting to like that this doesn't happen. I don't think the semantics are obvious in all cases. I mean, I know you were asking specifically for an AssociationNothing, not changing the current behavior, but still...

Comment: `Missing[]` as somewhat the role of `Nothing` for associations in the sense that the heads of the results of `<|a -> 1, b -> Missing[]|>[b]` and `<|a -> 1|>[b]` will be the same. And `DeleteMissing[<|a -> 1, b -> Missing[]|>[b]]` returns `<|a -> 1|>[b]`. It does not work as desired by OP for `Map`, though.

Comment: Missing has different semantic meaning to me.  "There should be something here but we don't have it." vs "This shouldn't be here."

Answer (score 6):

You could make a symbol that turned any `Rule` it is part of into `Nothing` with something like

```
In[28]:= ClearAll[associationNothing]
associationNothing /: Rule[key_, associationNothing] := Nothing

In[30]:= <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> associationNothing, "c" -> 3|>

Out[30]= <|"a" -> 1, "c" -> 3|>
```

but this means the substitution happens anywhere, not just in an association:

```
In[31]:= b -> associationNothing

Out[31]= Nothing

In[32]:= {c -> associationNothing, d, 3}

Out[32]= {d, 3}
```

If this isn't something you want to happen you could do some shenanigans with the stack to get around the rules for up values:

```
ClearAll[associationNothing]
associationNothing /: Rule[key_, associationNothing] := Nothing /; MatchQ[
    Stack[], 
    {___, Association, List, associationNothing, RuleCondition, MatchQ}
]
```

which should meet the requirements:

```
In[38]:= {c -> associationNothing, <|d -> associationNothing|>, 3}

Out[38]= {c -> associationNothing, <||>, 3}
```

I think it's crazy, but it just might work.

**narrator**: it does not work

The above shenanigans only work when constructing an association directly, it does not work when modifying an existing association:

```
In[49]:= assoc = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> associationNothing, "c" -> 1|>

Out[49]= <|"a" -> 1, "c" -> 1|>

In[50]:= assoc["d"] = associationNothing

Out[50]= associationNothing

In[51]:= assoc

Out[51]= <|"a" -> 1, "c" -> 1, "d" -> associationNothing|>
```

I don't know a way around this.

Answer (score 4):

`Nothing` inside a `List` evaluates to `Sequence[]` and thus vanishes completely from the arguments of `List`. One could emulate this behavior by replacing `y_->Nothing` with `Sequence[]` in the arguments of `Association`. Doing this manually by applying a function to a given `Association` would be one option another one (which I am hesitant to present but I am doing it anyway) is to modify `Association` itself to do this automatically:

```
Unprotect[Association]
Association[x___]:=Association@@(List[x]//.{a___,y_->Nothing,b___}:>List[a,b])/;MatchQ[List[x],KeyValuePattern[y_->Nothing]]
Protect[Association]
```

This works as `<|a->1,b->Nothing|>` results in `<|a->1|>`. Be aware that this potentially introduces overhead for `Association` or might even break functionality based on `Association`.